# How to use GDB to stop at the first line of c++ code of an executable?

Tags: c++, gdb

I have a C++ project. After using CMake compile in debug mode, it generates many executables.

I want to debug an executable suppose it called A.

But I don't sure where is the A's main function, so I want to use gdb to debug A and want to stop at its main function's first line.
How should I do? Thank you very much!

Comment: What’s wrong with `break main`?

Comment: [`start`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Starting.html#index-start) will put a temporary breakpoint at `main` and run until that breakpoint is hit.

Comment: You got some answers... do you have further questions? If not, it would be nice if you would accept the answer which solves your problem and if you feel it was a really good answer, you can also upvote it. Thats how we pay for other user work here :-) The important thing is, that other users will see that the accepted answer is correct and they can trust on it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To simply run until we reach main, we simply can

`> start`

which will set a temporary breakpoint at main and starts execution.

If you always want to break at main, even if you restart your program, you can add a persistent breakpoint and run.

```
>b main
>run
```

As we have maybe a lot of code running before main, especially if constructors of global objects are needed, it makes sense to beak already on the first instruction the program have. In that case we can use

`> starti`

which will stop on the first executed assembler instruction

We also can go to dedicated sections of the startup procedure, if we know the symbol names here. One example is `_init` on which you also can stop if needed. To get a more detailed list of possible breakpoints see: [gcc initialization](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Initialization.html)

If you need to stop on a known constructor, you can also set a breakpoint on all constructors of a class type if you simply use the constructors name, here given for a `class A` as example. This is very helpful if a global object is created before `main` is started. It helps a lot in the case you have dependent global objects which may fail as we all know [static initialization order fiasco](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof)

`>b A::A`